# Append in a particular format

Tags: for-loop, append

I need the following format
S_subno-brandno,brandno_subno-brandno

```
        deptBrandListName = cmbChannel.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[0].Trim() +"_"+"sdfs";

        for (int i = 0; i < chklstBrandList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            subNo[i] = chklstBrandList.Items[i].ToString().Split('-')[0];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < chklstBrandList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            brandNumber[i] = chklstBrandList.Items[i].ToString().Split('-')[1];
        }
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: S_ is not a problem...Remaining is the issue


I need the following format S_subno-brandno,brandno_subno-brandno